# Can´t attach vector Image from drawable to Email on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-intent

**Hello. I´m having problems attaching vector Images from drawable to an email. Execution says Can´t Attach empty File.**

```
public void enviarCorreu(View view) {

EditText t = findViewById(R.id.editText);
String email = t.getText().toString();

Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.face);

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
File f = new File(Uri.parse("android.resource://"+"com.example.m8_activitat2_tematicalliure/"+drawable).toString());

intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[]{email});
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,email);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Missatge enviat de la imatge");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.fromFile(f));

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Enviant Correu ... "));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem #1: You are using the wrong `Uri` scheme.

[The documentation for `EXTRA_STREAM`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_STREAM) states:

> A content: URI holding a stream of data associated with the Intent, used with ACTION_SEND to supply the data being sent.

You are using an `android.resource:` scheme, which is not `content:`. So, some apps which try to respond to your `Intent` will not know how to handle your `Uri`.

---

Problem #2: You are not providing a concrete MIME type.

You have:

```
intent.setType("image/*");
```

That is invalid. It is *your* content, so *you* must provide the MIME type.

---

Problem #3: There is no MIME type that represents a vector drawable resource.

You have no way of telling the receiving app what format this is in, as this format is not designed for passing between apps.

---

If you wish to use `ACTION_SEND` with `EXTRA_STREAM`:

- Use a `ContentProvider`, such as `FileProvider`, to serve your content, so you get a `content:` `Uri` to use in `EXTRA_STREAM`
- Have that content be of a recognize MIME type and use that MIME type in the `Intent` (e.g., `image/jpeg`, `image/png`)